# Removing formatting on PDF added with preview

Tags: preview

I'm reading a book in Preview (Lion) and i've highlighted some parts.

Is there any way to remove this formatting for printing or sending this book?

Answer (score 4):

- Go to Tools > Show Inspector (or use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>)
- In this window, click the pencil icon
- Select all your highlights (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> works here)
- Hit <kbd>delete</kbd>